# deployment in production azure function 2.0 using python 3.6 with visual studio code error

Tags: python-3.6, azure-functions

I'm currently trying to publish an azure function, using version 2.0 and a version of python 3.6.5, which I get success, but at the time of trying the url to call the function, it does not find it and it gives me a error code 404. I do not know what solution they have found, or if from azure portal it is still not possible to use azure function with python.

Answer (score 0):

I already found the solution, this happens because the python functions publication is in private preview.